# how to assign a radwindow property value from a public variable in page code?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

I have a radwindow and I'm trying to do this

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="winQuote" runat="server" NavigateUrl="popupQuote.aspx?serie=<%=  strSerie %>" Behaviors="Resize, Close, Maximize, Move">
```

When I get the value of the property **serie** using codebehind or javascript, it returns: serie=<%=  strSerie %>.

It is not parsing the <%= serie%> tag, it is using it as if it were text, any ideas my friends?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just set it in the code-behind.
If you need such functionality on the client use JavaScript - see the RadWinddow client-side API: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html and the setUrl() method that can be called after showing it.